# Div with 100% height with Display: Grid

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that has a header, a content area and a footer. And I want the footer to always be stuck to the bottom, while the content area always fills the remaining space. And I don't know how to do that.

This is what I have currently:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  /*position: relative;*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 3fr 3fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: teal;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: maroon;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">This is a header.</div>
  <div class="content">This is a content area.</div>
  <div class="footer">This is a footer.</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the content section doesn't stretch all the way to the footer section. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the content is longer than the page? There's a reason we don't use `position:absolute` and `display:grid`at the same time.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah okay, so I should avoid it unless I want stuff to overlap?

Comment: Yep....that's the issue. If you *don't* want the overlap then the answer below more or less solves it for you although I would use `min-height:100vh` rather than a fixed height. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dQreLV

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the tip - replaced `height` with `min-height`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;` - this way `footer` and `header` will take only space that they need, and `content` will take everything else. Also, remove `position: absolute;` from `footer` to make it a grid-item.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">This is a header.</div>
  <div class="content">This is a content area.</div>
  <div class="footer">This is a footer.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var h = $( window ).height();
    $('.container').css('max-height', h-220+'px');
});         
</script>
```

This is for container height if your footer height is 220px. You can change the height as per your need.

```
<style>
    .footer{ bottom:0; position:fixed; }
</style>
```

This is for footer to fixed at bottom.